# Hide LengthMenu from Jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Please how  do I hide the LengthMenu (the dropdownlist that displays number of records being shown per page) from my Jquery datatable?

Currently I am able to disable it, but I do not want it to appear at all. See  my [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jcSy4/1/)
below:-

```
testdata = [{"id":"58","country_code":"UK"},{"id":"59","country_code":"US"}];
$('#test').dataTable({
    "aaData": testdata,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "id" },
        { "mDataProp": "country_code" }
    ],
    "bLengthMenu" : false, //thought this line could hide the LengthMenu
    "bInfo":false,    
});
`//the next 2 lines disables the LengthMenu
//var aLengthMenu = $('select[name=test_length]');
//$(aLengthMenu).prop('display', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try with

```
$('#test').dataTable({
    "aaData": testdata,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "id" },
        { "mDataProp": "country_code" },
        { "mDataProp": "title" },
        { "mDataProp": "pubdate" },
        { "mDataProp": "url" }
    ],
    "bLengthChange" : false, //thought this line could hide the LengthMenu
    "bInfo":false,    
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcSy4/2/)

Answer (score 23):

Do it with:

```
"bLengthChange": false
```

This will hide the length dropdown.

Answer (score 11):

As of DataTables 1.10.18, according to https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthChange 
This is the recommended method to hide lengthMenu:

```
$('#example').dataTable( { "lengthChange": false } );
```

Cheerrs

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by disabling the pagination:

```
"bPaginate": false
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to disable the pagination.

Comment: Do you know how to customize pagination?

Answer (score 5):

To disable pagination at all, then do:

```
"paging": false
```

Answer (score 4):

If using bootstrap or some other templates, the result of hiding the length menu could get a little ugly, like, missing borders.

What worked for me was to use css and manipulate the label tag

```
.dataTables_length label { display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the pagination and "*Show X Entries*" drop down option ONLY when the data rows can fit in a single page, you can use `drawCallback`:

```
"drawCallback": function (settings) {
    var api = this.api();
    var totalRows = api.rows().data().length; //Get total rows of data
    var rowPerPage = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).data().length; //Get total rows of data per page
    if (totalRows > rowPerPage) {
            //Show pagination and "Show X Entries" drop down option
            $('div.dataTables_paginate')[0].style.display = "block";
            $('div.dataTables_length')[0].style.display = "block";
    } else {
            //Hide it
            $('div.dataTables_paginate')[0].style.display = "none";
            $('div.dataTables_length')[0].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can refer to [this discussion](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29843/hide-pagination-and-page-limits-unless-more-than-1-page-is-loaded), quite similar approach.